# Trying to get Powershell to work with an API

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a Powershell script to work with a Microsoft API, and being new to this, I have come across an error that I cannot seem to get past.

Error:

> ```
> Cannot find an overload for "UpdateDeviceValues" and the argument count: "3".
> At C:\PowerShellScripts\API-UpdateDeviceValues-ICC.ps1:13 char:37
> + $accounts = $pmws.UpdateDeviceValues <<<< ('18B81F1FD790','DisableICC','True');
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
> ```

From my searches, it seems that the API is requiring three values to be sent to it, but that is what I am sending.

My code:

```
$pmws = New-Object PrincipalManagement;
$pmws.Credentials = $cred;

$pmws.url = "http://172.31.9.2/bss/PrincipalManagement.asmx";

$accounts = $pmws.UpdateDeviceValues('18B81F1FD790','DisableICC','True');

$accounts
```

Any help with this error would be much appreciated.  I am rather new to this, getting Powershell to work with APIs.

This is the SOAP 1.1 example for the API.

```
POST /bss/PrincipalManagement.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.31.9.2
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.microsoft.com/iptv/bss/UpdateDeviceValues"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateDeviceValues xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/iptv/bss">
      <deviceExternalID>string</deviceExternalID>
      <deviceValues>
        <DeviceValue Key="string" Value="string" />
        <DeviceValue Key="string" Value="string" />
      </deviceValues>
    </UpdateDeviceValues>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can run this in PowerShell:

```
> $pmws | Get-Member
```

I get a long list of the APIs, and in that list is the one I am trying to use...

TypeName: PrincipalManagement
Name - MemberType - Definition
UpdateDeviceValues - Method - System.Void UpdateDeviceValues(string deviceExternalID, DeviceValue[] deviceValues)

Much thanks to Chamele0n!  Answer found!
I was missing how to properly format the parameters when calling the method. 
This works!

```
$Account = "18B81F1FD790"

$deviceValue = New-Object ($ns + ".DeviceValue") 
$deviceValue.Key = "DisableICC" 
$deviceValue.Value = "True" 

$accounts = $pmws.UpdateDeviceValues($Account, $deviceValue)
```

Thanks,
Jason...

Comment: As you can see from the definition, it plain doesn't take three arguments -- it only takes two, and the second one has to be an array of `DeviceValue` objects. Try `UpdateDeviceValues('18B81F1FD790', @(New-Object DeviceValue 'DisableICC','True'))` -- but if you're unlucky `DeviceValue` has no appropriate constructor and you have to go the long and tedious way of creating a `DeviceValue` object and setting the properties.

Comment: Thanks.   You are right.  I am needing two arguments, and the second one is an array.  Reading the documentation provided for this method, the two parameters are the 'deviceExternalID' and 'deviceValues'.  It states that the 'deviceValues' parameter is an array of objects with the new values.  In this case, the object is "DisableICC" which has the data type of "bool" and its value would be "True".

Comment: Tried > $pmws.UpdateDeviceValues('18B81F1FD790', @(New-Object DeviceValue 'DisableICC','True')) and received the error:  New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "DeviceValue" and the argument count: "2".  At line:1 char:54 + $pmws.UpdateDeviceValues('18B81F1FD790', @(New-Object <<<<  DeviceValue 'DisableICC','True')) + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Much thanks to Chamele0n!  Answer found!
I was missing how to properly format the parameters when calling the method. 
This works!
$Account = "18B81F1FD790"

$deviceValue = New-Object ($ns + ".DeviceValue") 
$deviceValue.Key = "DisableICC" 
$deviceValue.Value = "True" 

$accounts = $pmws.UpdateDeviceValues($Account, $deviceValue)